# Buttons dissapear in multiview (only in .net browser)

Tags: asp.net, .net, view, webbrowser-control, multiview

I have a page with a multiview containing 4 views.

I have no issues using this page with normal web browsers, but whenever I use the .net webbrowser control within a windows forms application the following happens:

View(0) loads perfectly with all controls
when I populated the fields and hit the submit button, view(1) loads.

In view(1) there is a datagrid, header and another submit button.
Everything but the submit button is visible on the screen for some reason.

Sometimes when I then use my cursor to randomly select sections of the webpage, the button suddenly appears.

To clarify: The button should be visible at all times, but isn't.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

.net web browser does not like

"position: relative"

in the css.